# I am close to admission to a PhD program. How should I get a co-supervisor from another school?

Tags: phd, advisor, supervision

I am close to be admitted to a PhD program. How can I get a co-supervisor from another school ? U21 is not the only alternative, but I did explore it. My potential school participates in U21. However, the other school did not respond to U21 emails.

1. Can I get a casual co-supervisor from another school?
2. Will the other school be mentioned on the degree as well?

Comment: Can you explain what U21 is?

Comment: http://www.universitas21.com/article/research/details/109/joint-phds

Comment: You're getting ahead of yourself. Get admitted first, find a primary adviser, and talk to her to find out how this usually works.